# Jquery / CSS – addClass to first:p of multiple div with specified class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using (trying to use) jQuery to add a class to the first paragraph of *every* div with class of ".djBio" My problem is that it's only adding the class to the first div.djBio, not *all* divs with that class. Here's the code. I am also using the fancy letter jquery plugin to add the drop cap to the first paragraph (which also is only applying to the first div.djBio, not all)

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    $('.servicesContent p:first, .about-usContent p:first, .djBio p:first').fancyletter().addClass('firstP');
});
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've stumbled over what everyone stumbles over at some point: `:first` doesn't really mean what you (at first) think it means. `:first` will *only ever return (at most) one element*. The best way I can think of doing your problem is using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$(function() {
  $(".servicesContent, .about-usContent, .djBio").each(function() {
    $(this).find("p:first").addClass("...");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the code like this to add the class to all of the first p tags:

```
$('.servicesContent, .about-usContent, .djBio').each(function() {
    $(this).find('p:first').fancyletter().addClass('firstP');
});
```

The problem with your code is it finds only the first instance of a p tag within a element with the given class.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) matches the first element of the selector you apply it to, and will only return (at most) one element.

You need to use the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), which will match any element that is the first child of its parent.  (Note that if there is a different element before the first `p`, it still won't work)

Comment: I realize that; that's what I meant by the parenthetical in my second paragraph.